# nopCommerce GLN(EAN) invoice

Tags: nopcommerce, invoice

I'm developing on a site based on nopCommerce 3.5 where my customer would like to use the danish "NemHandel" and invoice using EAN number.

Does anyone know of a plugin that can help with that in nopCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

We use  [PDF Plugin](http://nop4you.com/build-your-own-pdf-invoice-nopcommerce) and very happy. They also have helpful support.